# How to chart time of day in Google Spreadsheet with midnight crossover?

Tags: charts, google-spreadsheets

I'm struggling with the best way to chart a series of times in Google Spreadsheets that involves a midnight crossover.  The data in question is a graph of a bedtime, when the time to bed is after midnight the scaling of the chart becomes so great that important details and fluctuations in time are hard to see.  Google Spreadsheets doesn't seem to support AM/PM format times natively in the y-axis, thus the use of 24-hour time.

Ideally, I would like to have the y-axis range from 6pm to 6am.  Any thoughts or suggestions on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: I've been following this for several days and wondered if you got anywhere with this.  I initially spent some time looking at your problem and believe that renaming the vertical axis is possible with google's visualization add-on.  I wouldn't submit this as answer, as I have been unable to do it myself and would have to spend sometime playing with this to make it work.  You might want to take a gander at the contents of the visualization add-on.

Comment: @N8sBug I never did find an answer but just ended up graphing the data in a different manner.